# I am trying to write automation to be able to open an RDP and automate the applications that are opened in RDP. Can we do that?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have written code to open up an RDP connection but the RDP opens up as an IE. The same web link does not work in chrome/IE and the only way to open up that link is by using RDP connection. So, my question is can I automate the RDP opened IE like a regular IE?

Essentially, I want to perform some tests in the RDP opened IE but I can only get to opening it. since the RDP is a process and not a browser type, I cannot use it like a driver.

Comment: can you run selenium within the RDP session? Then it will be just like automating a local application

Comment: NO, i am not able to because RDP session opens up as a browser application and not like a normal RDP where we can access the files on the desktop. When I click on the .rdp, it opens up like a normal Internet Explorer page with the homepage.

Comment: Can't you get the system administrator to arrange it differently for you?